# Get MSIL from Assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, clr, il

Is it possible to usefully extract MSIL from an Assembly object without loading the type information?

I have a simple application that takes a string and attempts to dynamically create a method for making very fast calculations, but I want to avoid loading assembly/type information by using the `CodeCompileUnit` to compile a C# code string, extract the MSIL from the compiled assembly, and emitting the MSIL into a DynamicMethod. If this is possible.

Comment: It is not fully clear to me what you want to achieve, but it seems to me you're looking for a way to compile C# code while having it available as dynamically loadable method (and to achieve this copy the compiler generated MSIL) instead of invoking the compiled assembly?

Comment: I am yes. Invoking the compiled assembly seems to cause a memory-leak as the assembly cannot then be unloaded; and my application would potentially have a very large number of dynamically loaded methods.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) which helps you to read/modify/create assembly without loading them.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get MSIL is to call [MethodBase.GetMethodBody Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx). But it requires loading of type first.

Answer (score 1):

Use [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx) directly. For dynamic methods you don't even need a type.